# Maven war project copy website into webapp directory

Tags: maven, web-applications, build

I have a maven java web project and it build fine, and I have another website project (pure HTML/Javascript) which is outside the maven web project.

The directory structure is like:

```
project
|--backend
|--|--src
|--|--|--main
|--|--|--|--java
|--|--|--|--webapp
|--|--pom.xml
|--frontend
|--|--test
|--|--app
```

What I want to achieve is during the build in maven, copy the frontend/app directory into the webapp directory, before the WAR file is produced. How can I do that in maven?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the maven war plugin support this directly.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
   <webResources>
      <resource>
         <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
         <directory>../website</directory>
         <include>app/**/*</include>
         </resource>
     </webResources>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a maven plugin such as maven resource plugin